# import image on Pysimplegui

Tags: pysimplegui

I created this program that prints what you write on multiline I need to put an image next to multiline
the image should change based on what you write.
example: if I write home: I will see image 3
if I write dog: I will see image 2
and of defoult I will have image 1.

I looked online how it can be done but no site helped me.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from tkinter import N

import pathlib


sg.theme('DarkAmber')

WIN_W = 90   # dimensione
WIN_H = 25   # dimensione
file = None



menu_layout = [['File', ['New (Ctrl+N)', 'Open (Ctrl+O)', 'Save (Ctrl+S)', 'Save As', '---', 'Exit']],
               ['Tools', ['Word Count']],
               ['Help', ['About']]]


layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_layout)],
          [sg.Text('Terminal', font=('Consolas', 10),
                   size=(WIN_W, 1), key='_INFO_')],
          [sg.Text('Writhe here'), sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
          [sg.Multiline(font=('Consolas', 12), size=(WIN_W, WIN_H),
                        disabled=True, autoscroll=True, key='-OUTPUT-')],
          [sg.Button('SEND', bind_return_key=True), sg.Button('EXIT'), sg.Button('SAVE FILE')]]


window = sg.Window('sedia', layout, finalize=True)


def new_file():
    '''Reset body and info bar, and clear filename variable'''
    window['-OUTPUT-'].update(value='')
    window['_INFO_'].update(value='Terminal')
    file = None
    return file


def open_file():
    '''Open file and update the infobar'''
    filename = sg.popup_get_file('Open', no_window=True)
    if filename:
        file = pathlib.Path(filename)
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(value=file.read_text())
        window['_INFO_'].update(value=file.absolute())
        return file


def save_file(file):
    '''Save file instantly if already open; otherwise use `save-as` popup'''
    if file:
        file.write_text(values.get('-OUTPUT-'))
    else:
        save_file_as()


def save_file_as():
    '''Save new file or save existing file with another name'''
    filename = sg.popup_get_file('Save As', save_as=True, no_window=True)
    if filename:
        file = pathlib.Path(filename)
        file.write_text(values.get('-OUTPUT-'))
        window['_INFO_'].update(value=file.absolute())
        return file


def word_count():
    '''Display estimated word count'''
    words = [w for w in values['-OUTPUT-'].split(' ') if w != '\n']
    word_count = len(words)
    sg.popup_no_wait('Word Count: {:,d}'.format(word_count))


def about_me():
    '''A short, pithy quote'''
    sg.popup_no_wait('"ok boomer. Andreo')



while True:
    inputs = []
       
    event, values = window.read()

    if event in ('New (Ctrl+N)', 'n:78'):
        file = new_file()
    if event in ('Open (Ctrl+O)', 'o:79'):
        file = open_file()
    if event in ('Save (Ctrl+S)', 's:83'):
        save_file(file)
    if event == 'SAVE FILE':
        save_file(file)
    if event in ('Save As',):
        file = save_file_as()
    if event in ('Word Count',):
        word_count()
    if event in ('About',):
        about_me()
    if (event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT or event == 'EXIT') and sg.popup_yes_no('Do you really want to EXIT?') == 'Yes':
        break
    if event == 'SEND':
        window['-OUTPUT-'].print(values['-IN-'])
        print(values['-IN-'])
    

window.close()
```

Comment: Can you post your code and error (expected and actual result)?

Comment: I don't have an error because I don't have a code I don't know where to start (sorry)

Comment: You can refer scripts Demo_Button_Toggle.py, Demo_Button_Toggle2.py, Demo_Button_Toggle_Simple_Graphic.py in https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms

Comment: Then you can go to [Demo programs](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms), you can't just ask for code jsut like this.

Comment: ok i have a exempol for you but is mor long

Comment: i change my question with my code